# Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, is $N/[N,N]\cong N/[G,G]$ true?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here $[G,G]$ denotes the commutator, i.e., the least subgroup of $G$ containing $\{xyx^{-1}y^{-1}:x,y\in G\}$.

For convention, let $\tilde G$ denote the group $G/[G,G]$. This question comes from the following theorem:

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, then $\widetilde{G/N}\cong \tilde G/(N/[G,G]) $.

The point is that, if we have $\tilde N\cong N/[G,G]$, then we can simply write $\widetilde{G/N}\cong \tilde G/\tilde N$, which is very impressing. However, I'm stucked at proving the unique existing surjective homomorphism $\varphi: \tilde N\to N/[G,G]:g[N,N]\mapsto g[G,G]$ is injective, which is equivalent to proving that the inverse of $\varphi$ is well-defined. It is exactly to prove that $N\cap [G,G]\subset [N,N]$, but I have to admit that I'm not good at such things.

Any hints, methods, solutions or counterexamples are welcomed.

Comment: The commutator is _generated_ by the set $\{xyx^{-1}y^{-1}|x,y\in G\}$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Uh, thank you for reminding me this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any non-abelian group $G$ whose derived group $[G,G]$ is abelian gives a counterexample (namely an example in which $\tilde N$ and $N/[G,G]$ are not isomorphic). Indeed, taking $N:=[G,G]$, one gets $\tilde N \simeq N \not\simeq \{e\}$ since $N$ is abelian and $G$ is non-abelian. By construction $N/[G,G]$ is a trivial group, hence $\tilde N$ and $N/[G,G]$ are not isomorphic.

An example of such a group $G$ is $S_3$, whose derived group is $A_3$, which is a cyclic group of order $3$. A more interesting example is the Heisenberg group
$$
 H(\mathbf Z) = \left \{ \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & x & z \\
  0 & 1 & y \\
  0 & 0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix} \, : \ x,y,z \in \mathbf Z \right \}
$$
whose derived group is infinite cyclic.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think in this way...